# Unable to call API

Tags: node.js

**userAPI.js**

```
router.get('/:id',function(req,res,next){
    var user_id = req.params.id;
    if(req.params.id){
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
        db.query =(sql,[user_id],function(err,results){
            if(err){
                throw err;
                //res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
            }else{
                res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
    }
});
```

I am trying to `SELECT` the user with `id = 1` from database. The user exists but somehow in the above `db.query` did not get executed.

Here is how I am calling the API:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/1
```

Am I missing something in the code above ?

Comment: what is the returned response ? `404` ? can not get .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
db.query = ()
```

to

```
db.query(sql,[user_id],function(err,results){
            if(err){
                throw err;
                //res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
            }else{
                res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
            }
        });
```

Reason is that instead of executing `db.query` you try to assign something into `db.query`